# Extracting .node files

Tags: node.js, electron, discord

I found the .node files in the modules folder of Discord. I tried searching the internet but nobody has really asked a question about extracting .node files. I even tried to open up WinRAR but it failed to extract the `.node` file.

I tried to search or extract it but failed.

When I went to "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Discord\0.0.305\modules\discord_zstd"
it contains a `discord_zstd.node` file

On WinRAR, I tried extracting it but it says this: "`ERROR: This file is unsupported.`"

[.node file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb3ON.png)

Comment: Why say "some apps" when your tags and filepath specifically mention Discord?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.node` files are compiled [C++ addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), not archive files. You can't extract them (though you might be able to *decompile* them).